# Hide div when input has an assigned value

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototype

I'm trying to hide a div when the value = 10

Here is the code and [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cmorales/q7ktX/44/) working fine:

```
<script>
$('input[name=test]').keyup(function(){
  if($(this).val()<10)
    $('#yeah').show();
  else
    $('#yeah').hide();
 });
</script>

<label>Type whatever</label>
<input type="text" name="test"value="10"  />

<div id="yeah" style="display:none;">
<input type="submit"   />
</div>
```

But I'm trying to convert that code into Prototype code and I tried [this code](http://jsfiddle.net/cmorales/q7ktX/43/):

```
Event.observe(window, 'load', function () { 
$('input[name=test]').keyup(function(){
if($(this).val()<10)
$('#yeah').show();
else
$('#yeah').hide();
});
});
```

I only want to hide the div when input value = 10 into prototype code.

Please somebody can help me?

Comment: Based on your question, I do not see a statement of what is going wrong.  That said, you write `<10` in your code and `= 10` in your write-up.  Perhaps starting there will be of some help?  If not, then a prototype specialist may interpret your writeup to determine the question... or you could just state what is not happening.  You have already stated what you want to happen and provided the code, so 2/3 of the way there.

Comment: How could be the code using pure javascript? when the input value=10 the div will be hide, can you help me just with that? because I just want only that.

Comment: Have you tried `== 10` instead of `< 10`?  If that doesn't solve your question, then more can be proffered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the textbox an `ID`. For example:

```
<input type="text" id="txtbox" name="test" value="10" />
```

Change:

```
<div id="yeah" style="display:inline;">
```

To:

```
<div id="yeah" style="display:none;">
```

You need to use the [`$$`](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/dollar-dollar/) function which returns an [array](http://api.prototypejs.org/language/Array/).

```
Event.observe('txtbox', 'keyup', function () {
     if ($$('input[name="test"]')[0].value < 10){
         $$('#yeah')[0].show();
     }
     else{
         $$('#yeah')[0].hide();
     }
});
```

**Note:** You could also use `.first()` instead of `[0]`

## [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/W3V5M/6)

Comment: You have `> 10`.  I think you meant to write `== 10`

Comment: I thin it should be `<10` like the OP posted.. I have it the other way around

Comment: It is confusing, but the first line of their post says, "when the value = 10"

Comment: I think that matches the intention, even if not well-expressed by the OP. +1

Comment: Ok thanks...but can you help me using jquery min 1.4 or javascript pure? Just hide the div when input value=10 nothing else foget the rest.

Comment: Honestly, that is pretty hard... you will have to use `Listeners` or something... it would be easier if you didn't need `keypress` function... and why wouldn't your JQuery work in 1.4 min?

Answer (score 1):

you have a issue with prototype lib,

the Event.observe function is never triggered, secondly, you seem to still using the jquery api

```
$().keyup()
```

and you only load the prototype function.

Now days people rarely uses prototype, people use jquery for dom and underscore/lodash for iterations.