# How can fix Jquery conflict?

Tags: javascript

I created jquery code and when a value is assigned into the input ,this will show a div.

Here is the [demo working:](http://jsfiddle.net/e6BcS/31/)

```
<script>  
 $(document).ready(function () {
   if ($("#mont1").val() == '9') {
     $("#di1").show();
   }
 });
</script> 

<input id="mont1" value="9" />
<div id="di1">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</div>
```

But In my project I'm getting this error:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

I have lots of scripts:

```
<script src="/javascripts/prototype.js?1375798764" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="/javascripts/effects.js?1375798766" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="/javascripts/dragdrop.js?1375798766" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="/javascripts/controls.js?1375798766" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="/javascripts/application.js?1393972990" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="/javascripts/jquery/jquery-1.4.min.js?1375798764" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="/javascripts/jquery/easyTooltip.js?1375798764" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="/javascripts/jquery/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.min.js?1375798764"   type="text/javascript"></script><script src="/javascripts/jquery/jquery.wysiwyg.js?1375798764" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/jquery/hoverIntent.js?1375798764" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="/javascripts/jquery/superfish.js?1375798764" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="/javascripts/jquery/jquery_popup.js?1405027324" type="text/javascript"></script>  
<script src="/javascripts/jquery/jquery.validationEngine.js?1375798764" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="/javascripts/jquery/jquery.validationEngine-en.js?1403629546" type="text/javascript"></script><script src="/javascripts/calendar_date_select/calendar_date_select.js?1375798764" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="/javascripts/calendar_date_select/format_hyphen_ampm.js?1375798764" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="/javascripts/autoNumeric.js?1375798766" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Somebody can help me with this jquery conflict?

Comment: The div seems to be hidden, just as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/kHq49/. What exactly "does not work"? The problem in your jsFiddle is that `window.onload` is not executed because you are already running the code *after* the the page was loaded. Please make yourself familiar with the jsFiddle settings.

Comment: @FelixKling I think he meant if you change the textbox to 10, the div will be hidden.

Comment: @Thanatos Sama why not use jquery?

Comment: @nightingalez: Why not use React, angluar, knockout.js, prototype.js, or any other of these kind of libraries? These "why not use jQuery" comments don't add any value to figuring out the problem.

Comment: Maybe try to do that check also on change event. Define function and set it for both window.onload and input.onchange.

Comment: @FelixKling Really? Well don't judge too quickly as I am trying to put together a fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/e6BcS/ Everyone is trying to help with their set of skills.

Comment: I think, he wants to improve [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24689323/hide-div-when-input-has-an-assigned-value) into pure javascript

Comment: @ThanatosSama: Lets go back to your question first: What is the problem? If it just that in your jsFiddle the `div` is not hidden, that's because of the way you configured the jsFiddle. The code itself works fine. If you want to update the visibility when the input value changes, that's a different problem (something you haven't mentioned at all).

Comment: Now it's even less clear to me what the problem is. That's the first time you mention jQuery. [As I demonstrated](http://jsfiddle.net/kHq49/), the code you posted "works" fine.

Comment: @ThanatosSama OK, I have updated with jquery-1.4.min. Please check http://jsfiddle.net/e6BcS/2/ It seems that there might be some other problems with your code.

Comment: @nightingalez this fiddle you just given working fine.

Comment: Regarding the "real" answer: It doesn't make since to nest `$(document).ready(...)` calls. You just have to call it once.

Comment: Please remove comments or edit according to the edited question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with jsfiddle link what have posted:

Your script is wrapped in `onLoad` event. So this line fails to execute.

```
window.onload=function(){
```

Either you change the wrapped to `No wrap in head` it works fine. Or you may simply remove the annonymous function in the jsfiddle that will also do:

```
window.onload=function(){ //<-- remove this
   ...
} //<-- remove this
```

**EDIT:**

> script

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    $(document).ready(function () {
        if ($("#mont1").val() == '9') {
            $("#di1").show();
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: can you enter to chat? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57129/help-with-jquery

Comment: @ThanatosSama, I have update my answer as: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cmorales/e6BcS/26/)

Answer (score 0):

you can add a class wich appropriate style

```
.hidden { display: block; }
.inline { display: inline; }
```

in js

```
window.onload=function(){ 
  var inputval = document.getElementById("input-hi").value;
  var div = document.getElementById("div-hi");
  if (inputval == 5)
     div.className = "hidden";
  else
     div.className = 'inline';
}
```

Comment: How does this solve the problem? How is this different from setting the style directly with respect to visibility?